# Create a custom response to an HTTP request using c-icap

Tags: c, icap

I am using c-icap to modify HTTP transactions. According to the documentation. I should be able to do so by using the following functions.

```
int ci_http_response_create (   ci_request_t *  req,
int     has_reshdr,
int     has_body     
)
```

http://www.firefly.kutc.kansai-u.ac.jp/~k843966/c-icap/doc/group__HTTP.html

I tried this,however, all this does is add's to the response header's that are already there. I want to block the request from getting to the server and send my own customized response. Is there something else I need to do to be able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ci_http_response() is not for "modify" but "create".
if you want to modify service_io() or end_of_data()